# Auto adjust scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On this site (http://andrewgooch.com/suzuki-s-cross) when you scroll manually it will auto adjust onto the image. I'm sure this is jquery but I can't pinpoint how its done or even what its called (auto adjust?) to begin researching how to do this. Any initial guidance would be much appreciated!

I feel it's something like this.

```
$(document).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    //up
    if (deltaY > 0){
        scrollwheel = true;
        $.scrollTo.window().queue([]).stop();
    }
    //down
    else if (deltaY < 0){
        scrollwheel = true;
        $.scrollTo.window().queue([]).stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this to see if your code already works? A fiddle would help.

Comment: @ivy_lynx I stumbled upon this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kZY9R/ However, it just snaps to the next div underneath and won't adjust back upwards, only down.